# Audio and Video file

Tags: mono, monobjc

I am using mono 2.10.4 and monobjc. I want to be able to play H264 video file and an mp3 file. Monotouch has examples of playing the same on their web site(http://wiki.ios.xamarin.com/HowTo/Video/HowTo%3a_Playback_a_Video.). 
But can the same be accomplished using mono and monobjc ?. What would be the libraries that I would need ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [sample application named QTKitPlayer](http://www.monobjc.net/index.php?page=qtkitplayer) that demonstrate how to play a movie by using the QuickTime API; it is part of the Monobjc distribution.